# Magento 2 soap API in C#

Tags: magento2, api, soap-api-v2, c#

I've been searching for ways to use soap api in c# (with visual studio 2015). First I thought it was simple, just add web reference like this site (http://tdmts.net/2017/02/07/magento-2-soap-api-with-c-sharp-adding-service-references/) and I can use it. However, I've been trying few days and it is still not working.

This is the error message I got from the response:

Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-XXXXXXXXXXXX

so I checked log file,

`Message: The specified /var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/EavAttributeExtensionInterface.php.65214" file could not be written 
 Warning!file_put_contents(/var/www/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Api/Data/EavAttributeExtensionInterface.php.65214): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195`

I also checked the permission of this file, it is rwxrwxrwx.

I turned on the PHP soap extension in php.ini, but it seems that whether I turn it on or off, I get this same error message. PHP soap extension is existed and I did a simple test like this

```
    if (extension_loaded('soap')) {
        echo 'soap is here';
    }
```

The echo runs successfully.

Does anyone have this problem? Thank you in advance.